# Binding Grid.* от другого элемента

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Необходимо, чтобы элемент `textBlock` перемещался по `Grid`'у вместе с `comboBox`
Делаю так

```
        textBlock.SetBinding(Grid.RowProperty, new Binding("Grid.Row") { Source = comboBox});
        textBlock.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnProperty, new Binding("Grid.Column") { Source = comboBox});
        textBlock.SetBinding(Grid.RowSpanProperty, new Binding("Grid.RowSpan") { Source = comboBox});
        textBlock.SetBinding(Grid.ColumnSpanProperty, new Binding("Grid.ColumnSpan") { Source = comboBox});
```

MVS выдаёт ошибку

*System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Grid' property not found on 'object' ''ComboBox' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=Grid.Row; DataItem='ComboBox' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Row' (type 'Int32')*

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: _"перемещался по Grid'у вместе с comboBox"_ -- непонятно. куда они перемещаются? напишите подробнее

Comment: Необходимо, чтобы элемент textBlock перемещался по Grid'у вместе с comboBox. Т.е. перемещается comboBox, а textBlock должен это перехватывать по Binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ @Pavel Mayorov правильный, но для полноты, если вы действительно хотите установить Binding в code-behind, это лучше делать следующим образом:

```
textBlock.SetBinding(
    Grid.RowProperty,
    new Binding() { Source = comboBox, Path = new PropertyPath(Grid.RowProperty) });
```

Или если вы настаиваете на текстовых строках, то

```
textBlock.SetBinding(
    Grid.RowProperty,
    new Binding("(Grid.Row)") { Source = comboBox });
```

Comment: Да! Спасибо! Ваш ответ мне больше подходит, дабы не переписывать логику поведения элементов.

Answer (score 4):

Лучше оберните эти два контрола в еще один `Grid` - и перемещайте по внешнему `Grid`у уже его.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Так наверное правильнее.